Letter of Recommendation for PhD Application from Instructor with Master Degree
I am going to apply for PhD programs in the U.S. I graduated many years ago, and now I have been taking advanced maths courses online in the U.S from a very reputable university to prepare for my study. I did well in my class and fortunately, the instructor, who is a Msc holder and has been instructing advanced courses for many years, was willing to write me a good LOR. However, someone told me that it is more appropriate to have letters from PhD holders when applying for PhD programs.
I really appreciate having a letter from the instructor, who can speak for my readiness in mathematical background, so I hope it works out. I wonder what everyone's take is on my circumstances: will it be a fine if my letter is from a Msc holder?

If you are applying to competitive graduate programs, you want people writing your letters to be able to say "based on my experience mentoring graduate students, I think tofu would be the best graduate student ever". Readiness in mathematical background/"tofu did well in my class" only gets you to the bare minimum entry qualification. Everyone that applies needs to have completed all the mathematical prerequisites at a high level to even be considered. Assuming a competitive program, you're not admitted because you meet the qualifications, you're admitted because you are one of the best N applicants that application season.
So, I'd go a step beyond Buffy's answer: it's not just that you want your letter writers to have experience doing research, you want your letter writers to have experience knowing what it takes to be a successful PhD student in research, which ideally means supervising PhD students in research.
If you have no one else to write you letters, you have to go with what you have, but "fine" is not going to play well when other applicants have letters that are "great" or "excellent".

Continuing this logic, ideally your letter writer should also be from the same institution to which you are applying, the same age as the target PI, exact same subfield, etc. But we know that skills can transfer over these boundaries. OP shouldn't skip out on a strong letter of reference by overthinking narrow academic credentials. (And while I can't speak for OP's case, in private industry/R&D, it is not uncommon for someone with a master's degree to supervise PhD graduates in research. I've done it.)

What matters here is not the formal qualification of the referee, but what they can say about your ability at research.
A LOR from a PhD that simply states "This person did well in my class" is much less illuminating than a reference from - say - a research technician without an advanced degree who can praise your initiative at problem solving in a lab.
Of course it's better to have someone say good things about your classes than not, but doing well in courses is unlikely to be a differentiating factor for admission in a competitive program.

The real value of letter of reference for a PhD program is not necessarily about ability to research or lab acumen. It is bigger than that. A strong letter will tell the committee, if, in the expert (and experienced) opinion of the letter writer, that the prospective student is likely to succeed in the graduate PROGRAM (as a whole, research, classes, seminars, etc). This is where a letter from someone who has been involved in being a graduate advisor, and actively involved as faculty in a doctoral program is key. Many people with great hands in the lab still fail out of the PhD program.

Given that a PhD program is about publishable research and a master's degree holder might not have a lot of experience with that, yes, it is better to get letters from PhD holders. There are exceptions, of course, and some people can have that research experience without an advanced degree.
So, I can't say that your letter will be "fine". But you can only use what you have. A truly good letter, will honestly and accurately attest to your likelihood of success in a doctoral program and beyond. That implies both recent knowledge of you and your accomplishments, but also some knowledge of what that entails. Such letters are especially important in the US.
If this letter is one of three with the others more "appropriate" but equally strong, then there should be few issues.
However, the case will be judged by a few individuals and such a letter won't be the only consideration. So, you learn by making application. And, don't apply to only a narrow range of institutions. Cast a broad net.

As a caveat, I've known multiple researchers with only a masters degree who are widely published and well known in their fields. That includes one about 20 years younger than me, so it isn't just an 'old days' occurrence.
